# The rendered image has nothing to do with my animation

Tags: rendering, animation, image

so today I tried to make an animation got it finished, then started rendering it and it would load a image that had nothing to do with my animation, so there I waiting for like 3 hours to find a 10 second video of that image. Ok so it might be corrupted file but then I rendered it as an image and the images were that odd image... here is the video of what keeps happening:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kmg9wnbbu6g[help!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kmg9wnbbu6g)

Comment: What is the field of view of the camera, and when you press 0 on the number pad, what does it show you?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the top left of your screen it says **Object as Camera**.

[image]

In the scene section choose your camera as the active camera:

[image]